# Build array with all elements with specific class using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table with multiple rows. I need to get the text from specific rows and build an array which I can pass on and access later. I created a jsfiddle with the code that I am using:

https://jsfiddle.net/h6x2sqk2/3/

The problem is that everything is doubled:

```
[
  {
    "drdsc":"DSCDS0101101",
    "bkpsets":[
      {
        "backpset":"Backup1",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup2",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup3",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup4",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "drdsc":"DSCDS0202202",
    "bkpsets":[
      {
        "backpset":"Backup1",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup2",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup3",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup4",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Result that I need is:

```
[
  {
    "drdsc":"DSCDS0101101",
    "bkpsets":[
      {
        "backpset":"Backup1",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup2",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      },
      {
        "backpset":"Backup3",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "drdsc":"DSCDS0202202",
    "bkpsets":[
      {
        "backpset":"Backup4",
        "srvrolenotes":"",
        "setsize1notes":"",
        "setsize2notes":""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Had this fiddle open in my clutter of tabs, but the question has been answered. Posting it here as an alternative, but feel free to ignore it ;) https://jsfiddle.net/h6x2sqk2/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my suggestion here. What i did is to read from one backup till the other what you have in the tr sections

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/panvourtsis/ntxng3u2/)

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var dscarray = $('.bkpsrvdsc').map(function() {
      var $dsclient = $(this);
      var $rows = $dsclient.closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.drbkpsetdsc)');

      var drbkparray = $dsclient.closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.bkpsrvdsc)').find('.drbkpset').parent().map(function() {
        var $backuppset = $(this);
        var obj = { backpset: $backuppset.text() };
var $rows = $backuppset.closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.drbkpset)');
          obj['srvrolenotes'] = $rows.find('.srvrolenotes').val();
          obj['setsize1notes'] = $rows.find('.setsize1notes').val();
          obj['setsize2notes'] = $rows.find('.setsize2notes').val();

        return obj;
      }).get();

      var obj = { drdsc: $dsclient.text(), bkpsets: drbkparray };

      return obj;

    }).get();

  console.log(dscarray);
});
```

Comment: Almost there. The problem is that I am not getting the values for the textareas.

Comment: best approach though is to break it with classes under the same tr. Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

Your `$rows` get more then one row because `.nextUntil('tr:has(.drbkpsetdsc)')` runs through the complete `table` and not until the next `.bkpsrvdsc`
It could be easier if you put a table into a `td.bkpsrvdsc`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dscarray = $('.bkpsrvdsc').map(function() {
    var bkpsrvdsc = $(this);

    return {
      name: $(this).find('tr:first-child > td').text(),
      contents: bkpsrvdsc.find('.drbkpset').map(function() {
        return {
          backpset: $(this).text(),
          srvrolenotes: $(this).next('tr').find('.srvrolenotes').text(),
        }
      })
    }
  });

  console.log(dscarray);
});
```

```css
.bkpsrvdsc table {
  width: 100%;
}
table th,
table td {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 600px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>DSC#</th>
      <th>Check</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="bkpsrvdsc">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>DSCDS0101101</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td colspan="2" class="drbkpset">Backup1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Server role</td>
              <td><textarea data-autoresize rows="1" placeholder="Type notes here..." class="srvrolenotes"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td colspan="2" class="drbkpset">Backup2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Server role</td>
              <td><textarea data-autoresize rows="1" placeholder="Type notes here..." class="srvrolenotes"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="bkpsrvdsc">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>DSCDS0202202</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td colspan="2" class="drbkpset">Backup4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Server role</td>
              <td><textarea data-autoresize rows="1" placeholder="Type notes here..." class="srvrolenotes"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean changing `.nextUntil('tr:has(.bkpsetdsc)');`  to  `.nextUntil('tr:has(td.bkpsetdsc)');`  ?

Comment: This is just a very small example with 4 backup sets. In production I can have close to 100 backup sets so I don't think it would be advisable to have a table for each td.

Comment: You could add a pagination and don't show all at once. You can test this solution with up to 100 backup rows so you can find out the performance of this script. If it's not the best other people here may help you